# Angular Communicating from app component to a route

Tags: angular, service, router, communication

I am working on an Angular project with routing. I am already communicating from a route to the app component and updating its value there. However, when I try to send that information to another route (that may not be showing in the browser), I cannot access it. I just need this information in that particular route and would go with any method that can get this done.

In the app.component.ts I have

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
public message = "Discover Workouts";
public state:boolean = false; 

subscription: Subscription;
  
  //Inject MessageService
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
    this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage()
      .subscribe(mymessage => this.message = mymessage)
  }
ngOnInit(){
}
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

In workout-options.ts I have this

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter,  OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';
import { Sio2service } from '../sio2.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-workout-options',
  templateUrl: 'workout-options.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css']
})
export class WorkoutOptionsComponent implements OnDestroy{
mymessage: string;
subscription: Subscription;

@Output() public childEvent = new EventEmitter();
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {
this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage()
.subscribe(mymessage => { this.mymessage = mymessage; });
}

OnInit(){
 }
 
FupdateParent(exerName:string) {
    this.messageService.updateMessage(exerName);
//  this.sio2.sendMsg(exerName);
//console.log(exerName);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and in the message.service, I have

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
 
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MessageService {
    private myMessage = new Subject<string>();
 
    updateMessage(message: string) {
        this.myMessage.next(message);
    }
 
    clearMessage() {
        this.myMessage.next();
    }
 
    getMessage(): Observable<string> {
        return this.myMessage.asObservable();
    }
}
```

This far everything works fine. But when I try to receive in start-workout.ts (which is implemented as a route) the value sent by the latter component (which is also implemented as a route), I cannot.

Here is what I have tried.

In the start-workout.component.ts I have this (portion of the code)

```
export class StartWorkoutComponent implements OnInit{
public message = "";
subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private httpClient: HttpClient){
this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage()
.subscribe(mymessage => { this.message = mymessage; });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I have to be doing something wrong. Could someone please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
private myMessage = new Subject<string>();
```

Subject only fire to the those subscriptions which are subscribed at the time of firing the event. In order to get the data in the other route you have to change the message to ReplaySubject which provides the value everyone no matter when the subscription occures.

Check out RXJS documentation for more info about [Subjects](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) and [ReplaySubjects](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject)

solution: change message service

```
export class MessageService {
private myMessage = new ReplaySubject<string>();

updateMessage(message: string) {
    this.myMessage.next(message);
}

clearMessage() {
    this.myMessage.next();
}

getMessage(): Observable<string> {
    return this.myMessage.asObservable();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is your use of a `Subject`.  Your `StarWorkOutComponent` doesn't initialize until after the message emits its event.

If you use a `BehaviorSubject`, late subscribers will get the current value, so if a message is set, then you load that page it will start with the current value which your other component already set.

Note that when you create a new `BehaviorSubject` you will need to give it a value, so in your service make this change:

```js
// old
private myMessage = new Subject<string>();

// new, initialize with empty string, or you could use null as well in case your subscribers want to filter out cases of null and show their own default values
private myMessage = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
```

More details on `BehaviorSubject` can be found here: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject#behaviorsubject